# Visual similarity search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, image-processing, search-engine, similarity

I'm trying to build a utility like this http://labs.ideeinc.com/multicolr,
but I don't know which algorithm they are using, Does anyone know?

Comment: I'm not sure it is a "visual similarity" detection, more like color indexing (colors and area share). As color is made of numeric components, you can build algorithms to crawl into this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All they are doing is matching histograms.

So build a histogram for your images.  Normalize the histograms by size of image.  A **histogram** is a vector with as many elements as colors.  You don't need 32,24, and maybe not even 16 bits of accuracy and this will just slow you down.  For performance reasons, I would map the histograms down to 4, 8, and 10-12 bits.

- Do a fuzzy `least distance compare` between the all the 4 bit histograms and your sample colors.
- Then take that set and do the 8 bit histogram compare.
- Then maybe go up to a 10 or 12 bit histogram compare with the remaining set.  This will be the highest performance search, because you are comparing the total set with a very small number of calculations, to find a small subset.
- Then you work on the small subset with a higher number of calculations, etc.

The real big trick is to find the best algorithm for matching similar histograms.

- Start with the distance calculation.   In 3 dimensions i think it was:

  SQRT((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)

I'm doing this from memory, so look it up to make sure.

- For your purposes, you will have more than 3 dimensions, so you will have more terms.  A 4 bit histogram would have 16 terms, an 8 bit one would have 256 terms, etc.  Remember that this kind of math is slow, so don't actually do the `SQRT` part.  If you normalize the size of your images small enough, say down to 10,000 pixels, then you know you only will ever have to do `x^2` for values 0..10,0000.  Pre-calculate a lookup table of `x^2` where x goes from 0..10,000.  Then your calculations will go fast.
- When you select a color from the palette, just make a histogram with that color = 10,0000.  When select 2, make a histogram with color1=5000, color2=5000 etc.
- In the end you will have to add in fudge factors to make the application match the real world, but you will find these with testing.

Comment: thanks i will use imageJ and this programe algorithm
http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/color-inspector.html

Comment: I mention doing a fuzzy least distance compare.  I think I was on drugs.  Just do the least distance compare.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you do some kind of clustering of the colors present in the images in your database. I mean, for each image in your database:

- collect the colors of each pixel in the image
- perform clustering (let's say k-mean clustering with 5 clusters) on the collected colors
- store the clustered colors as representative descriptor of the image

When the user provides a set of one or more query colors you do some kind of greedy matching choosing the best match between the given colors and the color descriptor (the 5 reprsentative colors) of each image in your database.

What is the size of your image collection, because depending on the size some search indexing can be a bigger problem than the alogorith itself?

Answer (score 0):

Probably just creating a histogram of the colors used in the images, then doing a best fit to the user-selected colors.